# ExtJS class variable accessible to items array

Tags: javascript, extjs

my code is basically like this.

```
Ext.define('my.class.name', 
{
    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',
    variable:'',
    constructor: function(config)
    {
       variable = config.field;
    },
    items:[{
        xtype: 'text',
        text: variable // <- error
    }]
});
```

And I get that variable undefined. So my guess is that item objects can not access variables of its parent. How could I access those fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access variables in the configs, you need to do it in initComponent:

```
Ext.define('my.class.name', {
    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',

    variable:'',
    constructor: function(config) {
        variable = config.field;
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items:[{
                xtype: 'text',
                text: me.variable
            }]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```